# attribute having more than 1 value

Tags: xml

i have describe button caption property in xml button is like our mobile button which can may used to describe more than one character like a,b,c,2 or d,e,f,3 then store this information 
in xml file in easier manner to read it through c# program

Comment: Mangesh please try to rephrase your question it doesn't make any sense at the moment.

Comment: @mangesh: Please edit your question.  Add your XML code so we know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question.

But do you mean that attribute x can have values abc2?
Perhaps its better if you use child-nodes instead of attributes?